# Listview display random picture

Tags: android, listview, imageview

In my UI the first picture is always random, at first i  tryied to clean project and wipe personal data from AVD, but that does not help. Random only first picture, all other are shown properly. For the few seconds from the activity start, picture changes several times.

Please dont refer to duplicate of [Android ocasionally downloads images from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899801/android-ocasionally-downloads-images-from-url) as it is differenet (and solved) problem

[image]

```
public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService; 

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    int stub_id = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    public void DisplayImage(String uurl, int loader, ImageView imageView)
    {
        String url = uurl.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        url = url.replaceAll("\n", "%20");
        stub_id = loader;
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(loader);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;
        return downloadBitmap(url);

        //from web
        /*try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }*/
    }
    Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url){
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        URL url_1 = null;
        try {
            url_1 = new URL(url);
             bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url_1.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("Error while downloading bitmap from url", e.getMessage());
        }
        return bmp;
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u;
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }

        public void run() {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if(bitmap!=null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

filecash

```
public class FileCache {

    private File cacheDir;

    public FileCache(Context context){
        //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"TempImages");
        else
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    public File getFile(String url){
        String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
        return f;

    }

    public void clear(){
        File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
        if(files==null)
            return;
        for(File f:files)
            f.delete();
    }

}
```

memory cash

```
public class MemoryCache {
    private Map<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> cache=Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>());

    public Bitmap get(String id){
        if(!cache.containsKey(id))
            return null;
        SoftReference<Bitmap> ref=cache.get(id);
        return ref.get();
    }

    public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap){
        cache.put(id, new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));
    }

    public void clear() {
        cache.clear();
    }
}
```

utilis

```
public class Utils {
    public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
    {
        final int buffer_size=1024;
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
            for(;;)
            {
              int count=is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
              if(count==-1)
                  break;
              os.write(bytes, 0, count);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}
    }
}
```

adapter

```
public class CandidateAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    ArrayList<Candidate> objects;
    CandidateAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Candidate> candidates) {
            ctx = context;
            objects = candidates;
            lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          }
    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
      }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
      }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
      }
    Candidate getCandidate(int position) {
        return ((Candidate) getItem(position));
      }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // используем созданные, но не используемые view
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
          view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.inbox_list_item, parent, false);
        }
        Candidate p = getCandidate(position);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.from)).setText(p.get_name());
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subject)).setText(p.get_office());
        ((RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.rateindicator)).setRating(p.get_ranking());
        int loader = R.drawable.loader;


        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.photo);


        String image_url = p.get_photograph();


        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(ctx);


        imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, image);
        return view;
    }



}
```

activity

```
public class InboxActivity extends ListActivity {

    List<Candidate> candidates;
    private DatabaseHandler db;

    public void onDestroy(){
        if (db != null)
            db.close();

        super.onDestroy();
        //db.close();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.inbox_list);
        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        candidates = db.getAllCandidates(1);
        db.close();
        CandidateAdapter adapter = new CandidateAdapter(this,(ArrayList) candidates);
        ListView lvMain = getListView();
        //String numofrows = "" + candidates.size();
        //Log.d("Number of candidates", numofrows);
        lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
        lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.from)).getText().toString();
                Log.d("Name ", name);

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra("name", name);
                Log.d("Starting activity ", "Yeah ");
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });
    }





}
```

logcat warnings

12-16 08:35:33.525: W/Zygote(33): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080093 (res/drawable-hdpi/sym_def_app_icon.png) that varies with configuration!!

Can anyone help me out figure the problem here?

getall candidates function

```
public List<Candidate> getAllCandidates(int status) {
        List<Candidate> candidateList = new ArrayList<Candidate>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CANDIDATES;

        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Candidate candidate = new Candidate();
                if (status == Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(5))) {
                    candidate.set_name(cursor.getString(0));
                    candidate.set_office(cursor.getString(1));
                    candidate.set_photograph(cursor.getString(2));
                    candidate.set_promises(cursor.getString(3));
                    candidate.set_statment(cursor.getString(4));
                    candidate.set_active(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(5)));
                    candidate.set_ranking(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(6)));
                    // Adding candidate to list
                    candidateList.add(candidate);
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return candidate list
        db.close();
        cursor.close();
        return candidateList;
    }
```

Comment: db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        candidates = db.getAllCandidates(1); looks a bit suspect.
Can you show the query for getAllCandidates? what's the argument for?

Comment: Not read all the code yet but my first instinct is that the imageview is being re-used by the list and the async loading is not taking that into account

Comment: arguments is just to select candidates with active=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your imageView may be getting recycled by the listview. Your problem might be a stale reference to your image being passed to the ImageLoader.

You can verify this by checking the instance of the your imageView before you call DisplayImage and then after it's loaded.

```
ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(ctx);


        imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, image);
```

You may want to consider using the viewholder pattern to hold your ImageLoader rather than creating a new one each time, that may also help.

something like

```
ImageLoader imgLoader = (ImageLoader) view.getTag()
if(imgLoader == null){
imgLoader = new ImageLoader(ctx);
view.setTag(imgLoader);
}
```

This is just taking a stab at it. Hard to know without running it but hopefully it helps :)
Good luck